# Goland color for function names

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I have installed a custom theme. I am trying to customize two items. I forgot where I had seen it. I had done it in the past.

```
func myfunc
```

the `myfunc` I want to show up as bold in the editor window. And also, when we are in a function block, for ease, the name of the current function whose block we are in is also shown by intellij. I want to change the color of the function name and background of the bar so that I can read it easily. I am attaching a screenshot to make it easy to understand what I am trying to ask[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Settings (Preferences) | Editor | Color Scheme | Go" and there you can customize the Go code presentation to suit your needs.